# Pass stack tags to nested stack in Cloudformation

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, tags, nested, aws-cloudformation

I'm easily able to pass parameters to a Nested Cloudformation Stack using `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`, including referenced values:

```
"MyNestedStack" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
    "Condition" : "MyCondition",
    "Properties" : {
        "TemplateURL" : {
            "Fn::Join" : ["", ["https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/", {
                "Ref" : "S3BucketLocation"
            }, "/MyNestedStack.template"]]
        },
        "Parameters": {
            "MyVPC" : {
                "Ref" : "VPC"
            },
            "MySubnet" : {
                "Ref" : "ManagementSubnet"
            },
            "MySubnetAZ" : {
                "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ManagementSubnet", "AvailabilityZone" ]
            }
            "InstanceType" : "m3.large",
            "KeyName" : "MyKey",
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not able to find any documentation how to pass the Stack tags applied to the parent stack down to the child (nested) stack.

The original stack was called by:

```
#Create Stack
aws cloudformation create-stack --parameters ${parms} --tags Key='Environment Name',Value=${name} Key=Name,Value=${env} --stack-name ${env} --template-url ${url}
```

The `Environment name` and `Name` tags get applied to resources in the original stack, such as instances, but not to resources in the nested stack nor the nested stack itself.

Comment: AWS support confirmed that Stack tags don't automatically propagate: _You are absolutely correct, the stack-level tags are not propagated from top-level stack to its the nested stacks. We do have a feature request for this ability and I have surely added a +1 on your behalf. However, as with other feature requests we cannot ascertain when this feature will be launched._

Comment: If anyone else want's this option Amazon have mentioned the more people who do a request for this via a support case (a +1 to the feature); the quicker this feature may be greenlit for implementation.

Comment: In the meantime, a workaround would be to run a post create action (in this example with PowerShell) that could take the Nested stack name, and retrieve all AWS Resources of that stack. You can then tag with whatever you need on the results:
`$a = Get-EC2Tag -Filter @{Name="tag:aws:cloudformation:stack-name"; Value="MyStack-ChildStack-ZNJZH7EML46V"}; New-EC2Tag -Resources $a.ResourceId -Tags @(@{Key='Project'; Value='My Project'}, @{Key='Owner'; Value='Me'})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS have implemented propagation of stack tags to child stacks. I can't find an announcement or documentation reflecting this change, but it now works.

The [AWS CloudFormation Resource Tags Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html) page states:

> All stack-level tags, including automatically created tags, are propagated to resources that AWS CloudFormation supports.

In the below example Parent/Child stack templates the Stack Tags on the parent propagate to the EC2 instances in the parent stack, the child stack, the EC2 instance in the child stack.

Note: EC2 tags still don't propagate to volumes created from block device mappings.

**Parent Stack Example**

```js
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

    "Description" : "Test Child Stack Tag Propagation (Parent Stack)",

    "Parameters" : {
        "KeyName": {
            "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
        },

        "Subnet": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
        },

        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
        },

        "AMI": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Image::Id",
            "Default": "ami-f2210191"
        },

        "ChildTemplateUrl": {
            "Type" : "String"
        }
    },

    "Resources" : {
        "EC2Instance" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties" : {
                "InstanceType" : "t2.nano",
                "SecurityGroupIds" : [{"Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup"}],
                "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "Subnet" },
                "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
                "ImageId" : {"Ref": "AMI"}
            }
        },

        "InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
            "Properties" : {
                "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH access via port 22",
                "VpcId" : { "Ref": "VPC"},
                "SecurityGroupIngress" : [ {
                    "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
                    "FromPort" : "22",
                    "ToPort" : "22",
                    "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
                } ]
            }
        },

        "MyNestedStack" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
            "Properties" : {
                    "TemplateURL" : {"Ref": "ChildTemplateUrl"},
                    "Parameters": {
                            "Subnet" : {"Ref": "Subnet"},
                            "KeyName" : {"Ref": "KeyName"},
                            "AMI" : {"Ref": "AMI"},
                            "SecurityGroup": {"Ref" : "InstanceSecurityGroup"},
                            "VPC": {"Ref": "VPC"}
                    }
            }
        }
    },

    "Outputs" : {
        "InstanceId" : {
            "Description" : "InstanceId of the newly created EC2 instance",
            "Value" : { "Ref" : "EC2Instance" }
        },
        "IP" : {
            "Description" : "Private IP address of the newly created VPC EC2 instance",
            "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance", "PrivateIp" ] }
        }
    }
}
```

**Child Stack Example**

```js
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

    "Description" : "Test Child Stack Tag Propagation (Child Stack)",

    "Parameters" : {
        "KeyName": {
            "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName"
        },

        "Subnet": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id"
        },

        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id"
        },

        "AMI": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Image::Id"
        },

        "SecurityGroup": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id"
        }
    },

    "Resources" : {
        "EC2Instance" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties" : {
                "InstanceType" : "t2.nano",
                "SecurityGroupIds" : [{"Ref" : "SecurityGroup"}],
                "SubnetId" : { "Ref" : "Subnet" },
                "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
                "ImageId" : {"Ref": "AMI"}
            }
        }
    },

    "Outputs" : {
        "InstanceId" : {
            "Description" : "InstanceId of the newly created EC2 instance",
            "Value" : { "Ref" : "EC2Instance" }
        },
        "IP" : {
            "Description" : "Private IP address of the newly created VPC EC2 instance",
            "Value" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "EC2Instance", "PrivateIp" ] }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are `Tags` used here? I don't see this being used https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-tags

Comment: @Paolo the tags supplied with the stack creation command `aws cloudformation create-stack`. From the OPs question they were `Key='Environment Name',Value=${name} Key=Name,Value=${env}`

Comment: I see, I missed that. I was not using the CLI and I was looking for a way to pass tags from the parent stack to the child stack.. which is possible by using the `Tags` field

Comment: Even if you're using the console. The tags you apply to the parent stack in the UI will pass to the child stack. This is propagation of the actual CFN stack tags.

Comment: I was using a CloudFormation template