# Is there a way to add tags in the cloudformation templates to apply on resources and nested stacks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When creating a stack that also creates nested stacks, I need to input the tags for all my resources created manually, I would like to include this tags directly on my template and having this applied the same way is applied when I add this manually, is there a way to do this?

I have read that the child stacks are not affected by the tags on CF templates.

Comment: This has been answered before. Please refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613867/pass-stack-tags-to-nested-stack-in-cloudformation).

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate more, AWS documentation states

> All stack-level tags, including automatically created tags, are
>   propagated to resources that AWS CloudFormation supports. Currently,
>   tags are not propagated to Amazon EBS volumes that are created from
>   block device mappings.

Follow the example stated in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613867/pass-stack-tags-to-nested-stack-in-cloudformation).